# How can I cut up an image in Illustrator or Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop

I'm doing an assignment for my class where I'm supposed to rip a magazine article into bits and rearrange them into a different shape. But the teacher prefers things to be done in a program, rather than physical art. I've been trying to hours to "rip apart" my selected image in both Illustrator and Photoshop but haven't gotten anywhere.

What am I able to do to divide an image into a lot of little bits that don't all look identical without spending hours and hours on it?

And why is such a simple function to just cut up an image so seemingly impossible?

Comment: Welcome to **GD.SE** - please take a quick look round [tour] to see who and what we are - also glance over [ask] and [answer] a question, to get a sense of what makes a good query here, and how to frame it for best effect. Can you show us what you've tried and where that's failed for you? Screengrabs?

Comment: Are you trying to split a raster or vector image? If it's raster, Illustrator would be more trouble than it's worth for this particular operation.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Can you please respond to the questions asked by other users here. As currently written, your question doesn't have enough information to give a definitive answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

One appoach in photoshop could be to make a layer above the image where you draw "cut lines" with a 1px pencil tool (B).

Make that layer active then use magic wand to select one "piece", copy merged (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>) and paste. Repeat this for each piece and you have each piece on separate layers.

The drawback is that the pieces will loose 1 px, perhaps someone else have a better solution.

[image]
[image]
[image]